# Help with contour integral!

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: 
Consider the integral 
$$I_N = \frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}\pi} \oint_C \sin\frac{2z}{N}\cot (z)\,\mathrm{d}z $$
where $C$ is the rectangle with corners $\frac{\pi}{2} \pm \mathrm{i}$ and $(N-\frac{1}{2})\pi \pm \mathrm{i}$.  Show that
$$I_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}{N}\right) \text{.}$$

Use this to find the value of $I_N$ by considering the value of $$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\omega^n$$

$\omega = e^\frac{2i\pi}{N}$

Comment: Do we know anything about "$f(z)$"?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: When does $\sin(z) = 0$? Because they are simple poles, you can readily calculate the residues.

Comment: I thought I would have to use residue theorem, but the bit which threw me off was where it mentions the rectangle corners

Comment: The curve need not be smooth, just rectifiable (and closed).

Comment: so when I show $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} sin(2n\pi)$ do I just use the residue theorem